# Flutter Ios Github Actions Testflight

Tags: ios, flutter, github, testflight

I want to know what the pre-requisites are to deploy our Flutter iOS app which are in my private repo. I want to design the GitHub workflow.

1. ios should be deployed to TestFlight
2. Need to know the location where we can download the apk and ipa.

This is my pipeline

name: iOS CI/CD

on:
push:
branches:
- DEV-IOS

jobs:
build_ios:
runs-on: macos-latest
steps:
- name: Checkout repository
uses: actions/checkout@v2

```
  - name: Build
    uses: docker://sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli:latest
    env:
      SONAR_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SONAR_TOKEN }}
      SONAR_HOST_URL: ${{ secrets.SONAR_HOST_URL }}    
    with:
      args: >
        -Dsonar.projectKey=pfin-mobile-super-app
        -Dsonar.sources=.

  - name: Import certificates (iOS)
    env:
      BUILD_CERTIFICATE_BASE64: ${{ secrets.IOS_P_12_ENT }}
      P12_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.IOS_P_12_ih_PASSWORD }}
      BUILD_PROVISION_PROFILE_BASE64: ${{ secrets.IOS_PROVISION_STAGE }}
      KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD }}

    run: |
      # create variables
      CERTIFICATE_PATH=$RUNNER_TEMP/build_certificate.p12
      PP_PATH=$RUNNER_TEMP/build_pp.mobileprovision
      KEYCHAIN_PATH=$RUNNER_TEMP/app-signing.keychain-db

      # import certificate and provisioning profile from secrets
      echo -n $BUILD_CERTIFICATE_BASE64 | base64 --decode --output $CERTIFICATE_PATH
      echo -n $BUILD_PROVISION_PROFILE_BASE64 | base64 --decode --output $PP_PATH

      # create a temporary keychain
      security create-keychain -p $KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD $KEYCHAIN_PATH
      security set-keychain-settings -lut 21600 $KEYCHAIN_PATH
      security unlock-keychain -p $KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD $KEYCHAIN_PATH

      # import certificate to keychain
      security import $CERTIFICATE_PATH -P $P12_PASSWORD -A -t cert -f pkcs12 -k $KEYCHAIN_PATH
      security list-keychains -d user -s $KEYCHAIN_PATH

      # apply provisioning profile
      mkdir -p ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles
      cp $PP_PATH ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles
```

deploy:
runs-on: macos-latest
steps:
- name: Build and Archive iOS App
run: xcodebuild -scheme "Actions Productions" clean archive -archivePath "Actions" -configuration "Release Production"

```
    - name: Export IPA
      env:
        EXPORT_PLIST: ${{ secrets.IOS_EXPORT_PRODUCTIONS }}
      run: |
        # create export options
        EXPORT_PLIST_PATH=$RUNNER_TEMP/ExportOptions.plist
        echo -n $EXPORT_PLIST | base64 --decode --output $EXPORT_PLIST_PATH
        xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/Actions.xcarchive -exportOptionsPlist $EXPORT_PLIST_PATH -exportPath $RUNNER_TEMP/export

    - name: Upload IPA
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: ios-artifact
        path: $RUNNER_TEMP/export

    - name: Rename the file, remove whitespace
      run: |
        echo Export directory contents:
        ls $RUNNER_TEMP/export/
        mv "$RUNNER_TEMP/export/Actions Productions.ipa" "$RUNNER_TEMP/export/ActionsProductions.ipa"
        ls $RUNNER_TEMP/export/

    - name: Decode auth, API key file, and save it
      env:
        API_KEY_BASE64: ${{ secrets.APPSTORE_API_PRIVATE_KEY }}
      run: |
        mkdir -p ~/private_keys
        echo -n $API_KEY_BASE64 | base64 --decode > ~/private_keys/AuthKey_${{ secrets.APPSTORE_API_KEY_ID }}.p8
        echo "After saving"
        ls ~/private_keys

    - name: Upload file to TestFlight using CLI
      run: |
        echo "Starting upload."
        ls ~/private_keys
        xcrun altool --validate-app -f $RUNNER_TEMP/export/ActionsProductions.ipa -t ios --apiKey ${{ secrets.APPSTORE_API_KEY_ID }}
        xcrun altool --upload-app -f $RUNNER_TEMP/export/ActionsProductions.ipa -t ios --apiKey ${{ secrets.APPSTORE_API_KEY_ID }}
```